# How to create list order message in QuickFix/J

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I'm trying to generate a "list orders" (forex orders) to be executed by my TargetCompID with QuickFix/J lib.

If I correctly understand the FIX message standard, my message must have the following fields (I've put my values in parenthesis):

Header part

- 8 BeginString (FIX.4.4)
- 9 BodyLength (will be computed and provided by quickfixj when sending)
- 35 MsgType (E = NewOrderList)
- 34 MsgSeqNum (will be computed and provided by quickfixj whend sending)
- 49 SenderCompId (that's me)
- 52 SendingTime (will be computed and provided by quickfixj when sending)
- 56 TargetCompId (that's my counterparty which will execute my FX orders)

Then body part

- 66 ListId (uniq id computed)
- 68 ToNoOrders (count of my orders into list)
- 73 NoOrders (same count value as I will generate a complete list of order at once)

Then repeat list of following fields (one list fields per order in my list):

- 11 ClOrdId (my order id)
- 67 ListSeqNo (index of the order into my list: from 1 to N; N = ToNoOrders = NoOrders)
- ... several others fields as 15 (currency), 120 (SettlCurrency)

To do that I've done (in java / quickfixj):

```
Message message = new Message();
Header header = message.getHeader();
header.setField(new BeginString("FIX.4.4"));
header.setField(new MsgType("E"));
header.setField(new SenderCompID("it's me"));
header.setField(new TargetCompID("my counterparty"));
message.setField(new ListID(_fixListId));
message.setField(new TotNoOrders(_list.size()));
message.setField(new NoOrders(_list.size()));
int idx = 0;
for (Order order : _list) {
    message.setField(new ClOrdID(order.getId()));
    message.setField(new ListSeqNo(++idx));
    //message.setField(.... other fields to add to describe my order)
}
```

But doing this, in the callback function toApp of my quickfixj application (*"This is a callback for application messages that you are being sent to a counterparty"*), displaying the message in parameter (syso(message)) shows that only one order is inside my message, and it's the last oder I've put.

It seems they are some "group" we can create in QuickFixJ, and we can add several groups inside the same message. But there are a tons of kind of group, and I don't figure out what is the group appropriate for my "list order", if any? I see that there is a subclass of Message which is NewOrderList (it's my MsgType = E), but it's not a "group"; and it must be possible to create Message and provide MsgType directly...

Or maybe I don't understand correctly the FIX message standard and fields I have to provide?

Regards,

Alex

Comment: Ok, from http://btobits.com/fixopaedia/fixdic44/message_New_Order_List_E_.html; it said that "ClOrdID Must be the first field in the repeating group"; So I have to use repeating group... just to found how in quickfixj (and which one).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating a message from scratch, you should be using the predefined messages in QuickFIX/J.

In your case I would start looking at [`quickfix.fix44.NewOrderList`](https://www.quickfixj.org/javadoc/1.6.4//quickfix/fix44/NewOrderList.html).

By using this class, a whole lot of fields will be filled in for you in the header and footer part of the message (BeginString, BodyLength, MsgType, CheckSum, ...). You then only need to concern yourself mostly with the main part (ie body) of the message.

For the repeating group, there are helper classes available to set that information in the message. E.g. for [`NewOrderList.NoOrders`](https://www.quickfixj.org/javadoc/1.6.4//quickfix/fix44/NewOrderList.NoOrders.html):

```
quickfix.fix44.NewOrderList fixMessage = new quickfix.fix44.NewOrderList (
    .... // check constructor for what parameters to pass
);
// ...
quickfix.fix44.NewOrderList.NoOrders noOrders = new quickfix.fix44.NewOrderList.NoOrders();
// ...
fixMessage.addGroup( noOrders );
```

Comment: Yes I know that I can use predefined message. But I like to control what happens and then use the basic Message. And because my counterparty sent me spec about what they attend to receive, so by using predefined message, I'm not sure that all required (by counterparty) fields will be set. But ideally you're right. I've post my solution above.

Comment: @Alexxx I saw that =) always good that you can solve your own problems. The minium/conditionally required fields are governed by the dictionary though (set by configuration options). These reflect what the FIX standard requires. The counterparty can always ask for additional required fields, but there's no difference in that regard between using manual messages and predefined messages.

Comment: This wont work, as `NoOrders()` does not inherit from `Group`. You should instead use `new quickfix.fix44.NewOrderList.NoOrdersGroup()` and then add it to the message by using `addGroup()`. At least thats true for the C# version of quickfix

Comment: @Matze This works in QuickFIX/J. The question is about Java. In Java, `quickfix.fix44.NewOrderList.NoOrders` extends `quickfix.Group`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I've got it.

I've used generic group, and set Field manually.

So updated code solution is:

```
Message message = new Message();
Header header = message.getHeader();
header.setField(new BeginString("FIX.4.4"));
header.setField(new MsgType("E"));
header.setField(new SenderCompID("it's me"));
header.setField(new TargetCompID("my counterparty"));
message.setField(new ListID(_fixListId));
message.setField(new TotNoOrders(_list.size()));
message.setField(new NoOrders(_list.size()));
int idx = 0;
for (Order order : _list) {
    Group group = new Group(18, new ClOrdID().getTag()); //18 is the number of field I will add below inot the group, second paramaeter is the first field of the group
    group.setField(new ClOrdID(order.getId()));
    group.setField(new ListSeqNo(++idx));
    //message.setField(.... other fields to add to describe my order)
    message.addGroup(group);
}
```

Comment: Manual message building works, true. Using the predefined messages saves you quite some typing/management though.